# Java nested templates like A<B, C extends A> usage

Tags: java, templates, generics

I want to define the following Java class:

```
public class DummyTemplate<S, D extends DummyTemplate<S,D>> {

S value;
D next;
public DummyTemplate(S value, D next) {
    super();
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
}


public static DummyTemplate<String, DummyTemplate>  factory(){

    return  new DummyTemplate<String, DummyTemplate>("wohoo", null);
}

}
```

created so i can subclass:

```
public class DummyTemplateSubclass<S,  D extends DummyTemplateSubclass<S,D>> extends DummyTemplate<S, D>
```

(and the factoty of subclass returns DummyTemplateSubclass).

But the definition creates compile error:

```
Bound mismatch: The type DummyTemplate is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <D extends DummyTemplate<S,D>> of the type DummyTemplate<S,D>
```

Probably because the DummyTemplate  must have parameters, how to define it then?
i get the error

it compiles howewer only :

```
public static<D extends DummyTemplate<String,D>> D  factory()
```

but then i got trouble on subclass:

```
public static<D extends DummyTemplateSubclass<String,D>> D  factory(){
```

Name clash: The method factory() of type DummyTemplateSubclass has the same erasure as factory() of type DummyTemplate but does not hide it

Answer (score 2):

When you make a self-referencing template parameter like that, you can't use the template directly, because it's ever-expanding:

```
DummyTemplate<String, DummyTemplate<String, DummyTemplate<String, ...>>>
```

To use it, you must create a subclass:

```
public class DummyTemplate<S, D extends DummyTemplate<S,D>> {
    S value;
    D next;
    public DummyTemplate(S value, D next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

public class StringTemplate extends DummyTemplate<String, StringTemplate> {
    public StringTemplate(String value, StringTemplate next) {
        super(value, next);
    }
    public static StringTemplate factory() {
        return new StringTemplate("wohoo", null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `factory` method is `static` and the second parameter of `DummyTemplate` is `D extends DummyTemplate<S, D>`, you need to declare a new generic type, as follows:

```
public static <T extends DummyTemplate<String, T>> DummyTemplate<String, T> factory() {
    return new DummyTemplate<String, T>("wohoo", null);
}
```

Then the subclass compiles just fine:

```
public class DummyTemplateSubclass<S, D extends DummyTemplateSubclass<S, D>> extends DummyTemplate<S, D> {
    public DummyTemplateSubclass(S value, D next) {
        super(value, next);
    }

    public static <T extends DummyTemplateSubclass<String, T>> DummyTemplateSubclass<String, T> factorySubclass() {
        return new DummyTemplateSubclass<String, T>("wohoo", null);
    }
}
```

If you want to remove the `static` keyword from `factory`, then the code simplifies:

```
public class DummyTemplate<S, D extends DummyTemplate<S, D>> {
    S value;
    D next;

    public DummyTemplate(S value, D next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public DummyTemplate<String, D> factory() {
        return new DummyTemplate<String, D>("wohoo", null);
    }
}

public class DummyTemplateSubclass<S, D extends DummyTemplateSubclass<S, D>> extends DummyTemplate<S, D> {
    public DummyTemplateSubclass(S value, D next) {
        super(value, next);
    }

    @Override
    public DummyTemplateSubclass<String, D> factory() {
        return new DummyTemplateSubclass<String, D>("wohoo", null);
    }
}
```

Comment: public static DummyTemplate<String, D> factory() does not compile, also does not 
public static<D> DummyTemplate<String, D> factory()

Comment: @user184868 My apologies, I accidentally removed `static` from it earlier without noticing.  You should now be free to create a factory method for your subclass, but remember that `static` methods cannot be overridden in Java.

Comment: nah i still got 
Name clash: The method factory() of type DummyTemplateSubclass<S,D> has the same erasure as factory() of type DummyTemplate<S,D> but does not hide it

Comment: Yeah, you can't use the same name `factory` in the subclass, as `static` methods cannot be overridden.  I've named the method `factorySubclass` in `DummyTemplateSubclass`.

Comment: hmm, ok. <br>
now i tryed to use it not static like:<br>
 public  DummyTemplate<String,  D>  factory(){ <br> 
  return   new DummyTemplate<String,  D>("DummyTemplate", null);<br>
 }
then i subclass:<br>
public class DummyTemplateSubclass<S,  D extends <br>DummyTemplateSubclass<S,D>> extends DummyTemplate<S, D>{
and then<br>
DummyTemplateSubclass<String,?> dummy = new <br>DummyTemplateSubclass<>("noob", null);<br>
  
  DummyTemplate<String, ?> fa = dummy.factory();<br>
  
  System.out.println(fa.getClass());
returns class templates.DummyTemplate, but D must be DummyTemplateSubclass

Comment: @user184868 I've just edited the answer showing what the code would look like without `static`.